# How can I export a JavaScript-modified stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, export

I'm working on a web app which I'm making as customisable as possible. The app has a customisation page which consists of a toolbar and an iframe linking to a dummy preview file. Modifications made using the toolbar are reflected within the iframe so the user is able to see what they're changing. For example, there is a Font Size input field which can be used to adjust the preview page's `font-size`.

It works something like this:

```
<input type="number" id="txtFontSize" value="16" />

$('#sidebar').on('input', '#txtFontSize', function() {
    var
        previewFrame = window.frames['preview'].document,
        $body = $('body', previewFrame)
    ;

    $body.css({fontSize:25})
});
```

At the bottom of the toolbar there is a save button. I'm needing to export the JavaScript-modified stylesheet so that I can store the changes for that particular user. The method used for saving is irrelevant at this point; my question is this:

**How can I export the default stylesheet along with any JavaScript-modified styles?**

Before anyone asks: the format can be a simple string if that would be easiest. Otherwise there are under 100 users, so it wouldn't be out of the question to store these modifications as new CSS files per user instead.

Comment: You aren't modifying any stylesheet - you're changing the style of a specific element...

Comment: And it definitely seems relevant how you are saving. I would save everything in a database table that has `selector`, `key` and `value` (and some user identification) columns - which simply maps to CSS rules, that you can print on the page in a `<style>` when they visit the page. So when they save, you put all specific things changed into the table

Comment: @Ian I'm aware of that, I only worded it that way to make the question a bit easier to understand. I need to export a stylesheet with those specific styles included.